# how to backup a installed rpm package in redhat?

Tags: linux, rpm, package-managers

I was install a package by rpm command in redhat, but the package is failure now.
I want create a new package from installed package.
what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This command would help you in that,

```
rpm -Fvh –repackage rpm-file-name.rpm
```

Here `rpm-file-name.rpm` is an existing package in Linux which will be repackage by using above option.

From **man** page of rpm;

> `–repackage`    Re-package the files before erasing.
>
> `–replacefiles` Install the packages even if they replace files from
>   other, already installed, packages.
>
> `–replacepkgs`  Install the packages even if some of them are already
>   installed on this system.

Comment: Thanks, but you may not get the point of the question, I was install a rpm package, but the package is loss now, I want repackage from exists system  to new package, the 'rpm -Fvh –repackage rpm-file-name.rpm'  command be commint , the system echo "error: open of –repackage failed: No such file or directory.". sorry my english not well.

Comment: Well @GuohaoWang we use this command for taking back up of existing packages in system, and same you asked for as per i understand, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: sorry, my english not well, but I can use a example to explain my means. 1: rpm -qf /usr/bin/which (to query the package name) 2:now, the question is comming . how to build which-2.19-5.1.el6.x86_64.rpm. anyway, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

[`rpmrebuild`](http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net/) is built for re-creating RPM package files from already installed packages.  There are options which allow you to tailor the packaging, but the most simple invocation just produces an RPM file from an installed package.  Example: `rpmrebuild coreutils`